# egrep not behaving as expected when looking for one of three desired values

Tags: regex, grep

I'm writing a function that is supposed to automatically delete directories whose names meet a few prerequisites. One of these prequisites is that directories with a datestamp of today, yesterday or the day before yesterday are not deleted even if they otherwise fulfill the conditions. To that end, I fill three variables with the datestamps of today, yesterday and the day before that and plan to use them with "egrep -v" to exclude them from my for loop that is going to delete it.

The directory I am using as a testing directory contains the following files:

- FFFA72U_20160513
- FFFF11F_20160404
- FFFF12F
- FFFF13F
- FFFF17F
- FFFF21F_20130230
- FFFF99F_20160511

I've tried a lot of different combinations, but I can't seem to get the egrep part right. My code currently looks like this:

```
currentDate=`date +%Y%m%d`
yesterday=`date --date yesterday +%Y%m%d`
bYesterday=`date --date="2 days ago" +%Y%m%d`

for i in `ls ./*targetdir* | egrep -i "^[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]_[0-9]{8}$" | egrep -iv "(${currenDate}|${yesterday}|${bYesterday})$"`
do
*actions here*
done
```

When the above executes, I expect it to return the two files that have the 20160404 and the 20130230 datestamps, but I get no matches whatsoever.

Removing the double-quotes around the egrep string gives me an error that the ( is unexpected, so that does not help. Replacing the double-quotes with single quotes also generates no output.

When I prefix both parentheses with a / or a \, it returns all four directories with a datestamp while I expect it to exclude the ones with a May 2016 datestamp.

I've tried many more small tweaks (e.g., escaping the pipes) that I can't perfectly recall/repeat here, but it boils down to the fact that I have no clue whatsoever why it is not generating the desired outpout.

At this point I'm a bit flabbergasted by it all and I'd really appreciate any pointers because even after all my attempts and reading several topics on this matter I don't really see a simple way to get the script to do what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo: `currenDate` instead of `currentDate`. Empty alternative matches all records, the inverse matches none.

Comment: I was somewhat afraid that this was going to be something that'd make me feel stupid. I've been staring at this for hours. Thanks!